# android studio error: cannot access zzbgl after make project but no error if you Rebuild

Tags: android

This is app module and tried removing **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'**
and changing the version to **17.0.0**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: it wasn't in the code I just added firebase dependency to the project and it started showing the error. If I remove it then no error but I need it.

Comment: Then please describe your problem in question, so that people can understand and provide you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error was due to conflicting dependencies versions. i changed the firebase versions to:

````
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}```
````